# C convert integer (from macro) to string at compile time

Tags: string, time, compilation, macros

I have a situation when I have to get a value of a macro and convert it to string in compile-time, this code will be executed on a microcontroller, so I don't want anything to be executed at run time. 
Code snippet: I want to but (FREQ_FINAL) inside (MCU_INFO_STRING) as a string.

```
#define FREQ_INPUT              8000000UL   // External Crystal or Clock Frequency (Hz)
#define FREQ_FINAL              (FREQ_INPUT * (_PLLDIV+2)) / ((_PLLPRE + 2) * (_PLLPOST + 1) * 4)

#define MCU_INFO_STRING         "HW: TTKM V2.10\n"\
                                "FW: V2.35\n"\
                                "MQTune_USB: V2.00\n"\
                                "Freq: (Here I want to but FREQ_FINAL) Hz\n\n"
```

Comment: There's no way to do constant folding in a macro in the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this sort of thing is to have a separate program that you build and run at build time to generate the string that then gets included in the final binary.

If you're using `make` to build your project, this is reasonably easy to do.  You can add a rule that has a source file of your project as the target and runs the auxiliary program to generate that file.

Comment: Thank you, Chris, for your answer, I am looking for an easier solution where no make file intervention will take a place, the compiler will clear the make file and re-create it after every build, and I am still in the development phase.
If you have another solution, even if it was a Radical Solution, that is limited to the code itself, I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: @AlMoutazBillah -- If you really want to use C, you could do your own very simple preprocessor that performs "mail merge" that produces the source code you want. You only need 1 or 2 lines generated that way, so how hard can that be? But you can also use any number of scripting environments / languages, like Lua or Python. Or you could switch to Clojure or other language that would have the code generating code ability built in. So IMHO, you should accept this answer, even though you don't like it.